# Using regexreplace to surround numbers by parentheses

Tags: google-sheets, regex

The data I'm starting with:

> 1 Hello
>   2 Just another 22 line
>   300 Yeah, the first step is to admit you need help

I want the "finished" version to look like:

> (1) Hello
>   (2) Just another (22) line
>   (300) Yeah, the first step is to admit you need help

To recap: surround any numbers with parentheses.

I can identify the numbers easily in the REGEXREPLACE "find" section, with `[0-9]+`

I am completely lost in the replace section. How do I retain the matched string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is in cell A1, then

```
=regexreplace(A1, "([0-9]+)", "($1)")
```

will do the job. The term you were looking for is *capturing*: the parentheses around `[0-9]+` capture the matched substring, i.e., it gets recorded somewhere. In the substitution string, the commands $1, $2, ... can be used to refer to the 1st, 2nd, etc captured string.

So, the command says: find a string of consecutive digits (greedily, i.e., grab all consecutive ones), and replace it by the same string surrounded by parentheses. And being a global search-and-replace, `regexreplace` does the above to every matched substring.

Comment: I initially had `\d` there (as I tend to use), but let's admit it: if `\d` ever matched one of [these digit characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), I wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Normal Human, thank you very much!  Today, you are Above-Normal Human at least to me.  :)  I appreciate the clarity of your answer and the example.  "Capture" huh?  Learning can sure make you feel dumb!  But I'm _that_ much less dumb now.  Whoo hoo!